# What is trainable parameter in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

tf.compat.v1.layers.batch_normalization takes `trainable` as an input. The documentation says:

> Boolean, if True also add variables to the graph collection GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES (see tf.Variable).

I think only scaling factor (gamma) and offset (beta) should be added to trainable variables and I am skeptical if even moving averages will get added to GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES. Can somebody tell me how trainable input is influencing the behavior of batch_normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this function is [deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization) and should not be used.

`trainable` arguments means that scaling factor (gamma) and offset (beta) will be trainable and it's true by default.

When it comes to moving averages, those **are not trainable**, they are only updated after each batch pass, those are not parameters (`tf.Variable` objects).

Please notice, you can set `trainable` to false, in such case, if `beta` and `gamma` are set to defaults (zero and one respectively), they won't affect the moving averages. You can turn them off by issuing `center` (for `beta`) or `scale` (for `gamma`).